# What is the interpretation of speed of a travelling wave, based on $\frac {\partial x}{\partial t}$ formula

Tags: waves, velocity, speed

Motion satisfies the wave equation if the following holds true 
$$\nu^2 * \frac {\partial ^2 \psi} {\partial x^2} = \frac {\partial ^2\psi} {\partial t^2}$$ where $\psi$ is the vertical displacement of the medium (if a transverse wave), $x$ is the position of each particle whose displacement is being considered / the position at which the displacement is considered, $t$ is the time elapsed, and $\nu$ is the velocity of the wave in the transverse direction.

Also,
$$\nu^2 =\left(\frac {\partial x}{\partial t}\right)^2$$

from most general considerations of velocity.

My question is this:

I think that the velocity of the wave can be interpreted as 'the speed at which the $x$-value at which a certain displacement can be found changes'. That would make sense, given that the velocity is also $\frac {\partial x}{\partial t}$, and this is, literally, the rate of change of a position on a string / in a medium, wrt time. 
Why is it that this, the velocity, is commensurate with $\frac {\partial x}{\partial t}$, when $\frac {\partial x}{\partial t}$ implies, I think, that position of a particle / part of the medium is changing with respect to time, i.e that $x$ and $t$ are not independent? They seem from prior consideration to be independent.

In the wave equation, $\psi$ is varying with respect to time and position, which is why the derivatives make sense when taken wrt those values. The positions $x$, are positions in the medium (say, along a string), and they are fixed points, which are used as reference points for calculating amplitude ($\psi$).

So how does it come that there is a formula, and we work with it, where $x$ and $t$ don't seem to be independent variables, because we take the derivative of one with respect to the other, and it has meaning?

Is it just a mathematical formality, because we have something that can be written in terms of $x$ and in terms of $t$, and so they can be written in terms of each other (and the function is differentiable), so a derivative exists?

How comes it (if it does) to have that meaning I ascribed to it earlier, of the change in position, $x$ with respect to $t$, where a particular amplitude of the wave can be found (which is what the velocity is)?

Comment: $x$ and $t$ are both independent variables; taking $\frac{\partial x}{\partial t}$ doesn't make much sense in the first place.

Comment: I think so... But I don't understand what v can be if not that. They look very independent. But, how do I understand the horizontal velocity of the wave - it seems as if the varying thing, for the horizontal velocity, is the place a displacement $\psi$ can be found. How do I relate this to the original wave equation and the quantities there?

Comment: re "and ν is the velocity of the wave in the transverse direction" --should that not be longitudinal?  v is in the direction of wave propagation.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your description of the horizontal velocity as "the speed at which the
$x$-value at which a certain displacement can be found changes" is perfectly fine, and is usually termed the "[phase velocity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Phase_velocity)" when discussing solutions of wave equations.

It comes directly from the fact that the solutions may be written as functions of a combined variable like this: $\psi(x,t)=\psi(\phi)$ where $\phi=x-vt$, or $\phi=x+vt$. More generally, any linear combination of $\psi(x-vt)$ and $\psi(x+vt)$ will be a solution.

If we fix $\phi$, the value of $\psi$ remains constant. The positions $x$ at which $\phi$ (the phase) remains constant satisfy $x=vt$, or $x=-vt$, if we have one of these elementary solutions.

Although $x$ and $t$ are indeed independent variables, if one focuses on a point of constant $\phi$, such as the crest of a wave, as a function of time, a velocity $v=\pm x/t$ emerges from the equation $\phi=$ constant.